# What defines whether or not a wolf becomes hostile?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft, what actions does the player need to avoid in order to keep the wolves peaceful so they don't murderously devour the player? I was just walking, and I attacked a sheep. All of a sudden I had three wolves on me which, when I attacked them backed,it only added more wolves to the fray.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As has already been stated, untamed wolves will only attack you if you attack them, regardless of whether it is by hitting them with a sword, a tool, a porkchop, or even your bare hands. Note that even projectiles which cause no damage (such as thrown eggs or snowballs) will still cause passive mobs (e.g., Wolves and Zombie Pigmen) to become hostile.

[According to the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wolf#Behavior_and_appearance): *"When a wild wolf attacks a sheep, **they will appear to become hostile**, but will not attack the player."* In your case, I'm guessing the wolves were going for the same sheep as you. You, seeing the evil look in their eye thought they were aggressive towards you and attacked them, causing them to retaliate.

Comment: This seems very likely, considering not *all* the wolves were hostile until after the retaliation. If they'd become hostile to the player in the normal fashion, there wouldn't have been any "hanging back" to join in later.

Comment: @IQAndreas yeah your probably right

Answer (score 2):

Don't hit them and they won't attack you.

Comment: O.k. that's great. what else? Apparently when I even jump on a wolf it attacks me.

Comment: @YoungGuilo Please describe your actual problem if you want more than a textbook answer. You may have found a glitch or a bug or just done something accidentally that you didn't notice, but if you don't describe your situation or tell us why you're asking, then it's just a basic one-sentence question and you *will* get basic one-sentence answers. We're not mind readers.

Comment: Are these tamed wolves?  Not sure about the current version, but in older versions, your wloves would attack you if you shot youself with an arrow.

Comment: The wolves might attack if they take environmental damage as well, but overall, they *do* need to take damage to become hostile.

Answer (score -2):

You will always know a wolf is hostile by angry eyes, but other than hitting them, I realize there is another way to anger them. I was taming wolves in my house, and they appeared to turn hostile by looking through stained glass.